# onclick function preventing smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have a button on my website that is linked to a div at the bottom of the page. It works fine until I add an onclick event for a function. Is there anyway to get both to work?

Here is my code

HTML:

```
<a href="#req" class="req_btn">text</a>


<script type = "text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        //my function
    }
</script>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(".req_btn").attr( "onclick", "myFunction()" );
```

When adding the jQuery and the function, if you click on the button, it just turns to a blank white page instead of scrolling to the bottom. Anybody know why?

Thanks

Comment: What does the `myFunction` do ? And you should use `jQuery(".req_btn").on( "click", myFunction);`

Comment: It is a very bad idea to bind function that way, by manually overwriting the `onclick` attribute. Just use a simple event listener as stated in the comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Try binding the onclick event like this:

```
$('.req_btn').click(myFunction)
```

Comment: thanks! that worked, the function executes but some reason the screen still turns blank. its probably something to do with the function

Comment: Where have you given id="req" ?